# Bazel doesn't find tensorflow packages for C++ example code

Tags: linux, tensorflow, package, bazel, arch

I try to make [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) work, but everytime I try to build the program with bazel I get this error message:

```
bazel build //code:label_image 
ERROR: /home/jonas/tensorflow/code/BUILD:12:1: no such package 'tensorflow': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//code:label_image'.
ERROR: /home/jonas/tensorflow/code/BUILD:12:1: no such package 'tensorflow': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//code:label_image'.
ERROR: /home/jonas/tensorflow/code/BUILD:12:1: no such package 'tensorflow': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//code:label_image'.
ERROR: /home/jonas/tensorflow/code/BUILD:12:1: no such package 'tensorflow': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//code:label_image'.
ERROR: /home/jonas/tensorflow/code/BUILD:12:1: no such package 'tensorflow': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//code:label_image'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//code:label_image' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.261s
```

I saved the exact source code from github in a directory called `code`. I installed `tensorflow` in an (active) virtual environment via pip: `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`. I use arch linux.

Why doesn't bazel find the proper packages? I'm quite new to bazel/tensorflow. Where are these packages saved? Do I have to specify them explicitely somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, extracting a subfolder from a project that uses Bazel and building it separately does not work.

If you look into the BUILD file of the `label_image` folder, you will see this definition for a C++ binary:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "label_image",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    linkopts = select({
        "//tensorflow:android": [
            "-pie",
            "-landroid",
            "-ljnigraphics",
            "-llog",
            "-lm",
            "-z defs",
            "-s",
            "-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": ["-lm"],
    }),
    deps = select({
        "//tensorflow:android": [
            # cc:cc_ops is used to include image ops (for label_image)
            # Jpg, gif, and png related code won't be included
            "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
            "//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib",
            # cc:android_tensorflow_image_op is for including jpeg/gif/png
            # decoder to enable real-image evaluation on Android
            "//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_image_op",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
            "//tensorflow/core:core_cpu",
            "//tensorflow/core:framework",
            "//tensorflow/core:framework_internal",
            "//tensorflow/core:lib",
            "//tensorflow/core:protos_all_cc",
            "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        ],
    }),
)
```

This rule tells Bazel what the `label_image` binary requires to be built. Notably, it has dependencies (`deps`) and link options (`linkopts`) that point to the root of the tensorflow workspace (`//tensorflow`, defined by the `WORKSPACE` file), which is missing from your extracted subfolder. This is the reason why Bazel is complaining that it cannot find the package `tensorflow`.

The easiest way to build the `label_image` binary is to build it from within the tensorflow project, since the paths are already set up.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it enough to just download the complete project from github, and run the example build in there, or do I need to build something in advance to make it work?

Comment: Yes, and follow the Tensorflow-specific additional steps in the README to download the model definition if you haven't.